# Gatsby + Jest - How to enable support for the experimental syntax 'jsx'?

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, gatsby

Following Gatsby unit test docs:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/unit-testing/#writing-tests

I got this error:

Details:

```
SyntaxError: ../Projects/gatsby/testing-first-steps/src/components/__tests__/header.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (9:15):
```

```
       7 |   it("renders correctly", () => {
       8 |     const tree = renderer
    >  9 |       .create(<Header siteTitle="Default Starter" />)
         |               ^
      10 |       .toJSON()
      11 |     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
      12 |   })
```

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!** 
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/babel/#how-to-use-a-custom-babelrc-file

Add this:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-gatsby
```

then in `.babelrc` file add this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "babel-preset-gatsby",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```